# Call function after window reload using same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

```
$('#start').click(function () {
   window.location.href=window.location.href;
   runme();
});
```

This is my simple goal, every time user click the start button, I want the page to reload but still call the custom `rume` function. Please let me know if this is possible or there are other way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you just reload the page with button click and run the `runme()` function inside `document.ready` function. that should do it for you.

Comment: you can put your runme function inside page load event and every time page loaded this function will be run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you reload the page JS run again from start, So you can't directly trigger some function after page reload.
But in order to achieve this, you can use, [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

So, you can do something like:

```
$('#start').click(function () {
    sessionStorage.setItem('callRunMe', '1')
    window.location.href=window.location.href;
});
//On Page load 
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('callRunMe')) {
        runMe();
        sessionStorage.removeItem('callRunMe');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks just checking on it, Im trying to set a normal variable awhile ago but I think session is what will fullfill my requirements

Answer (score 1):

Place your `runme` inside `$(document).ready`, and just use `location.reload()` to reload the page. Use `localStorage` to make sure this only happens when you click a button:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("clickedStart") runme();
});
$("#start").on("click", () => {
    localStorage.setItem("clickedStart", "true");
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: This will trigger the function even if the page loads for the first time.

Comment: @I need the function to run only when the button was clicked

Comment: @bumbumpaw I have used sessionStorage in my answer, and I think it will fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

you can set a flag into `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` and get the flag after document ready.

```
var SOTRAGE_NAME = 'needRunme'

$('#start').click(function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem(SOTRAGE_NAME, true);
  runme();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   var isNeedRunme = sessionStorage.getItem(SOTRAGE_NAME);
   if(isNeedRunme){
       runme();
   }
})
```